# Tikz Gantt Chart Remove Canvas Top and Right Lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, pgfgantt, charts

With `canvas/.append style` we can customize the canvas lines or remove it as the code below.

```
canvas/.append style={fill=none, draw=none}
```

I would like to know how to remove only the Top and Right canvas lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly what you ask for, but to the same effect. Use `draw=none` in the `canvas` style, but add `name=canvas` in addition. You can then use the node anchors of that node to draw the left and bottom border, by placing the `ganttchart` environment inside a `tikzpicture`, and adding the appropriate `\draw` after `\end{ganttchart}`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{ganttchart}[
canvas/.append style={
   fill=none,
   draw=none,
   name=canvas % node name for the canvas, used below
   }
]{1}{12}
\gantttitle{2011}{12} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\
\ganttgroup{Group 1}{1}{7} \\
\ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{2} \\
\end{ganttchart}

% draw partial frame
\draw ([xshift=0.5\pgflinewidth]canvas.north west) |- ([yshift=0.5\pgflinewidth]canvas.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I appreciate it, thank you. Result: https://i.imgur.com/ZAAh0D2.png